# fetch users from table 1 by searching in table 2?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table called experience the columns are

```
id   |  userid  |  expid
1       2          3
2       2          4
3       2          8
4       1          4
5       6          4
```

how do i fetch users from table called users with column userID matching expid from table experience?

so far i have this but need help with the sql query to see results?

```
<?php
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
 $exp = $_POST['exp'];
if($action=='experience_search'){
foreach ($exp as $fetch){
    echo $fetch."<br />";


    }
?>
```

thanks a ton

Comment: PHP has several different methods for connecting to a mysql database. Which verison of PHP are you using and which method? Are you using a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This where the [MySQL Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) is applicable.

Assume that you want to get the `first_name` of the user from the `users` table matching `expid` `8`.

```
SELECT experience.*, users.first_name FROM experience
JOIN users on users.id = experience.user_id
WHERE experience.expid=8
```

Comment: I want to fetch every data of the user

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL JOIN for this purpose.

```
Select * FROM users INNER JOIN experience ON users.id = experience.userid;
```

This will pull all matching records from both tables. If you want specific files from either table just replace

> *

with ., ., ...

To know more about SQL JOIN read [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

Hope this help you.

Comment: here is my actual table but not getting results

$query = "SELECT * FROM candidate_experience JOIN candidate_form on candidate_form.id = candidate_experience.candidate_id WHERE candidate_experience.exp_id='".$fetch."'";

Comment: You need to share table scheme for a better response from the community.

Comment: sorted thanks a ton :)